# Implementing Cocos2D with UIKit (IB)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to build a framework for a rather extensive iOS application that will combine UIKit (and all the conveniences of Interface Builder) with Cocos2D (a powerful game engine). My goal is to design all of the app's GUI with IB, and when necessary, initialize a view encapsulating Cocos2D. With this design I hope to keep the two frameworks separated from each other.

A Cocos2d template project comes with an AppDelegate class that spends some time setting up an EAGLView, building the CCDirector, and connecting the two. For example, the consider the `applicationWillFinishLaunching` method implemented in the AppDelegate (below). My question is this-- **what should I comment out in this function if I don't want to immediately start out with a Cocos2D view, but instead the MainMenuViewController I have created?**

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];

director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];
director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Display FSP and SPF
[director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

// set FPS at 60
[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

// attach the openglView to the director
[director_ setView:glView];

// 2D projection
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

// Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
// It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
// You can change this setting at any time.
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

// Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

// Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
navController_ = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

// for rotation and other messages
[director_ setDelegate:navController_];

// set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

// make main window visible
[window_ makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My immediate thought is to scrap the glView and everything related to it. I'm a little unclear on the workings of setting the MyNavController, setting the director's delegate, and the rootViewController, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, and I have done it before following this tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit)

The tutorial is a bit outdated with an older version of cocos2d, and does not use storyboards, but you should be-able to get the basic idea from this.

Comment: Thanks Bob. That was one of the first tutorials I followed. I am very, very unclear on the whole point of the 'rootViewController' in that example, however. Might you be able to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in an app. What I did was create a .xib called CocosViewController that is presented whenever a user launches a story book (the story books are displayed in cocos2d while the rest of the app is UIKit). This view is nothing special but just a plan view controller with a single view inside it. I just add the cocos director to a UINavigationController, and present that controller. When setting up the GL view I match the frame with the size of the view controller.

Here is an example of code that can be used to setup cocos2d. I end the scene if it is already running or else you'd get a nasty opengl error if the scene was already running. Although it shouldn't happen if you end the director when the view is unloaded.

```
    @interface CocosViewController ()
    {
        UINavigationController* navController_;
        CCDirectorIOS* director_;
    }

    @end


    @implementation CocosViewController

    -( void ) setupCocos2d
    {
        director_ = ( CCDirectorIOS* )[CCDirector sharedDirector];

        if( [director_ runningScene] != nil )
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];

        CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[self.view bounds]
                                       pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                       depthFormat:0
                                preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                        sharegroup:nil
                                     multiSampling:NO
                                   numberOfSamples:0];

        director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];
        [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
        [director_ setView:glView];

        [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

        if( ![director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
            CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

        CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
        [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];
        [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];
        [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];
        [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];

        [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:NO];

        navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
        navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        [director_ setDelegate:navController_];
        [self presentViewController:navController_ animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

I call this in viewDidLoad. It is largely what occurs in a cocos2d app delegate in the template projects. Don't forget to end the director [CCDirector sharedDirector] end] when the view unloads once you are done with it.

Let me know if you have any more questions. Hope this helped.